# How several WAP (Wireless Access Points) handle interference?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan

I am now trying to resolve slow wifi problem. While investigating it, I understood I need more information, that is:

1. How several access points negotiate (if at all) channel to be used?
2. How it is possible that two access points which cover same area work simultaneously and on the same channel and both transmit/receive data at the same time? Is some kind of time-division multiple access mechanism is used?

I would appreciate if you could point me to any specification which would help me to answer my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained concisely in
[Wikipedia Wi-Fi Operational principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi#Operational_principles).

The algorithm used is
[Carrier-sense multiple access with collision avoidance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-sense_multiple_access_with_collision_avoidance),
whose main principle is "listen before transmitting" followed by an optional
"Request to Send/Clear to Send (RTS/CTS)".

This algorithm minimizes collisions, but cannot completely prevent them.
When a station receives multiple signals on a channel at the same time,
this causes corruption and will require stations to re-transmit,
thus reducing throughput.

This is how the algorithm works:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Prior to 802.11ax the answer to both your question is "they don't"

The reason why WiFi slows down and latencies spike is because their is no communication between APs. If APs have an auto mode they may periodically scan for broadcasting ssid's and pick the least congested.

I believe 802.11ax has something called "colouring" to help APs under different control to work together.

As 802.11?? are IEEE standards you can purchase the standard docs from them - https://standards.ieee.org/standard/802_11-2016.html

Comment: Just reread your last paragraph - the standards are  802.11n 802.11ac and 802.11ax - there are other (older) ones as well. The WIFI Alliance may also be if assistance.